# How to tally the expression with operator precedence table in C?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I know the following code is not a good way to write expressions in C and there might be a lot of post already discouraging such post, but I am sure the output is not compiler dependent.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 2;
    int y = 1;
    int z = x || ++y;
    
    printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Now in this I know that short-circuiting would happen and `++y` is never evaluated but if I am not wrong, unary operators have higher precedence than logical operator and hence `++y` should happen first and the expression should short circuit from the reverse direction right?
2. Also one more issue is that if the short-circuit starts happening from the left side, then `x` is evaluated first and then because of short-circuiting, the value of x should be assigned to `z`, but it is getting answer to be 1. Why so?

Comment: Operator precedence is for figuring out a parse without parenthesizing everything. It is not not the precedence in terms of evaluation order.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica But in some other cases the precedence is respected in terms of evaluation. Moreover, how to figure out the order of evaluation in such cases?

Comment: || is a logical operator, since the result will be Boolean (true), which is converted to int (1).

Comment: Sometimes rain falls when I'm in a bad mood. Does that mean my mood affects the weather? Every expression has an evaluation order for its operands (or they are unsequenced). You don't need to know most of them since good code (a) doesn't write crazy expressions (b) parenthesizes when needed.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Unfortunately such good codes are okay while writing code but not for some MCQ exams where after giving such snippets they ask us the output of `x, y, z`

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate that so menu venues are terrible at teaching how to actually do this job.

Comment: @infinitezero Thanks that answers the second question but still not the first one

Comment: Short-circuit evaluation itself tells that it won't evaluate the second operand unless needed. When there is no evaluation of the operand/expression, then there's no question of precedence. Precedence of operators is considered only for the evaluated portion of the expression.

Comment: The technical term for the currently evaluated portion of code is called a sequence point. Logical operators, ||, && introduce a sequence point between their left and right operands. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point

Comment: "But in some other cases the precedence is respected in terms of evaluation."  Such as what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order) article on Cppreference is a useful resource here.

#### Question 1

There is a difference between the *operator associativity* and the *order of evaluation*. The former specifies how a (sub)expression is parsed, or in other words "where to put the parentheses". The latter deals with if and in what order subexpressions are evaluated.

Quoting the example given on Cppreference:

> [..] the expression `f1() + f2() + f3()` is parsed as `(f1() + f2()) + f3()` due to left-to-right associativity of operator+, but the function call to `f3` may be evaluated first, last, or between `f1()` or `f2()` at run time.

There are several rules concerning the order of evaluation. An important concept here, is the *sequence point*:

> If a *sequence point* is present between the subexpressions E1 and E2, then both value computation and side effects of E1 are sequenced-before every value computation and side effect of E2.

The statement `int z = x || ++y;` contains a sequence point, due to the use of the logical-OR operator:

> 2. There is a sequence point after evaluation of the first (left) operand and before evaluation of the second (right) operand of the following binary operators: `&&` (logical AND), `||` (logical OR), and `,` (comma).

Combining the two quotations, this means that `x` will be evaluated first. Since `x` is non-zero, the right side of the OR expression is not evaluated and the logical-OR operator has the result `1` (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical)). This also means that the side-effect of `++y` does *not* take place.

This behavior is defined according to the C standard, and is thus *not* compiler dependent (i.e. not *implementation defined*).

#### Question 2

The logical-OR operator does *not* result in `x` here, because it represents a boolean value. In C, for all boolean expressions, this the `int` type `1` for a true expression and the `int` type `0` for a false expression.

#### Output

The code will print `2 1 1` for `x y z`, as `x` and `y` are unchanged since their initialization and the logical-OR operator resulted in `1`.